# Twitch API returning incorrect channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitch, twitch-api

I'm currently working with the Twitch API and for some reason making a GET request to `/api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels?query=[STREAMER_NAME]` seems to be returning the incorrect streamer/user. Here is an example:

`/api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels?query=loltyler1` returns the incorrect user since the `broadcaster_login` is wrong. `"broadcaster_login": "loltyler1dotcomdiscoalpha"`

This doesn't seem to just happen with this specific account. Another example was when **imkaicenat** was used as the query and it returned a user called **imkaidenbtw**. Here is an example from a function making a GET request to their api from my own code, hopefully this isn't a problem on Twitch's end and there's something here that can be fixed:

```
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  // split message into array of words
  const args = msg.content.split(" ");

  // If bot sends message end functions
  if (msg.author.bot) return;

  // Get info
  if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}live`)) {
    // Make get request to Twitch API with streamer name
    axios
      .get(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels?query=${args[1]}`, {
        headers: {
          "client-id": process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.TWITCH_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        let response = res.data.data;
        response[0].is_live
          ? msg.reply(
              `${response[0].broadcaster_login} is live playing ${response[0].game_name}. Watch here: https://twitch.tv/${response[0].broadcaster_login}`
            )
          : msg.reply(`${response[0].broadcaster_login} is not live`);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
```

Not sure if it helps, but this is part of a discord bot project. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few months ago I also had to deal with `Twitch`'s `API` I had the same issue. If you `log` your `res` variable you should notice, that it returned a lot of `streamers` with **similar** names

In order to get the desired one, you have to filter the `data` you are receiving. Also you have to use [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) first:

```js
const streamer = 'name of the streamer'.toLowerCase();

[...]

.then(res => res.json())
.then(res = {
   if(!res.data) return console.log('Streamer not found!');
   
   const broadcaster = res.data.filter(filter => filter.display_name.toLowerCase() === streamer)[0];
})
```

---

#### Note:

If you want, you can take a look at my [`twitch live command`](https://github.com/Toasty65/DiscordBot-Jarvis/blob/develop/commands/twitch/liveNotification.js) but I'll point out that I'll have to **recreate** this one since it's not quite robust. **But for your problem** you can orient yourself well on it

Comment: Filtering is exactly what I needed, thanks!